# Extract list of genes that only appears in both List 1 and List 2

Tags: r, rna-seq

I have two lists of differentially expressed genes one from knockout A vs control and the other from knockout B vs control cells. However the list shows slightly different genes being expressed in KOA than KOB, as such I want to create a final list containing only those genes which appears in BOTH KOA and KOB but not mutually exclusive in either. Both lists of genes have same column names and are contained within .csv files.

How would I go about this in R as I am completely lost.

Thanks,
-Yaseen

Comment: Hi @YaseenAhammed, can you provide a bit more information about your files, is it only one column? Have you read them into a data.frame?

Comment: use ```inner join(KOA,KOB,by = "common column name")```

Comment: would inner join remove all those entried that only appear in KOA but not KOB and those appear only in KOB and not KOA?